# Unable to install latest python in Amazon Linux 2 instance due to openssl issue

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssl

I tried installing Python3.11.8 using source file. After installation, I am unable to import ssl getting `ModuleNotFound error due to OpenSSL version less than 1.1.1`.

So, I installed 3.2.1 version. I exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `bashrc`.

When I run `openssl version` command as part of terminal, I get `3.2.1` but when I get `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` as part of python3.11.8 env, I am unable to import.

And in case of existing Python3.7 version, I am able to `import ssl` but unable to get the latest version `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` through python3.7 env. Instead I get 1.0.2 openssl version. Due to this, I am unable to import `urllib3` & other dependencies.

Can you help resolve above issue?

Comment: Hello. I assume you are using/referring to an ec2 instance? If that is the case, this article might be useful as it did help me install python version 3.10 in a cloud9 instance (that was using Amazon Linux 2). https://repost.aws/questions/QUqD8nfai4Tly2jSpzNOo2AQ/setting-up-aws-cloud9-with-python3-9-runtime-and-urllib3

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install `python3.8.6` successfully using [this documentation](https://thilinamad.medium.com/building-python3-from-source-with-custom-openssl-installation-9821b4cc4741#:%7E:text=Install%20Python%20with%20Custom%20Installed%20Openssl&text=Go%20to%20the%20python%20official,%2Fpython%2D386%2F%20page).